# Exception occuring while using T Field<T> in my code

Tags: c#, .net, datatable, dataset

I am getting InvalidCastException when i am trying to use this code.
I am not been able to resolve how to use Field.
Plz help me out

```
DataTable _Transaction= new DataTable();
float NetAmount=0;
//Records inserted into Table 

  for (int i = 0; i < _Transaction.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                NetAmount += _Transaction.Rows[i].Field<object>("ItemAmount");
            }
```

**EDIT** I actually want to retrieve value at specified columnName and Row no from a dataTable.
_Transaction is a name of table here

Comment: Where does it occur? What is NetAmount? Why does Transaction starts with an underscore?

Comment: @zneak I dont know too much naming conventions. I m a starter only. Rest I have mentioned. It would be gud if u could provide me a link of all naming conventions in .net

Comment: Tip: to iterate over all rows in a DataTable, use `foreach`: `foreach (DataRow row in _Transaction { /* do something with row */ }`.  This is slightly more idiomatic than using a for-loop with an index (but it's mainly a style thing -- don't worry, your for loop still works fine!).

Comment: here's a fairly common naming convention: http://www.irritatedvowel.com/Programming/Standards.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to cast or convert `_Transaction.Rows[i].Field<object>("ItemAmount")` to the same type as `NetAmount` so that the `+=` operater will be operating on a single type.

For example, if `NetAmount` is a `decimal` and the field is also a decimal use `Field<decimal>` instead of `Field<object>`. If the field is not a decimal, use `Convert.ToDecimal` on it.

Comment: @jball: I tried to cast it into same type but when it didn't worked then i typecasted it to bigger type.

Comment: The `ItemAmount` column in the row has a type, and we don't know what it is, but you do; if you provide that type, it will work, I promise.  That's how you're supposed to use `Field<T>`.

Comment: @Shantanu, I've added an explanation of the two options that you have, which, as mquander pointed out, depend on what type the column is, and is something that you'll need to know to solve this.